# Proper way to use a join?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not sure how to properly use a join to get the data I'm looking for.  I'd like to show a lookup_name for each column.

table 1

```
+----------+----------+----------+
|Small City| Med City | Big City |
+----------+----------+----------+
|    22    |    44    |    23    |
+----------+----------+----------+
|    29    |    35    |    88    |
+----------+----------+----------+
|    29    |    26    |    24    |
+----------+----------+----------+
```

Table 2

```
+----------+----------+
|    ID    |  Name    |
+----------+----------+
|    22    |   Paris  |
+----------+----------+
|    23    | Wichita  |
+----------+----------+
|    24    |  Dallas  |
+----------+----------+
|    26    |   Omaha  |
+----------+----------+
|    29    |   Barn   |
+----------+----------+
|    35    | Houston  |
+----------+----------+
|    44    |  Austin  |
+----------+----------+
|    88    |   Miami  |
+----------+----------+
```

I want to select from table 1 but display the lookup value in each row instead of the id.

I don't even know if join is the right way to do it.

Comment: I don't think that this is what SO was meant for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select
t1.Name as `Small City Name`,
t2.Name as `Med City Name`,
t3.Name as `Big City Name`
from table1 t
inner join table2 t1 on t1.ID = t.`Small City`
inner join table2 t2 on t2.ID = t.`Med City`
inner join table2 t3 on t3.ID = t.`Big City`
```

Comment: Thanks, this put me on the right path.

Answer (score 1):

try this (the trick is to use `table2` *three times*):

```
select sc.Name,
       mc.Name,
       bc.Name
  from table1 t,
       table2 sc,
       table2 mc,
       table2 bc
 where t.SmallCity = sc.ID and
       t.MedCity = mc.ID and
       t.BigCity = bc.ID
```

Or using *join syntax*:

```
select sc.Name,
       mc.Name,
       bc.Name
  from table1 t 
         join table2 sc on (t.SmallCity = sc.ID),
         join table2 mc on (t.MedCity = mc.ID),
         join table2 bc on (t.BigCity = bc.ID)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Select 
  t1.[Small City], 
  t2s.Name as SmallCityName, 
  t1.[Med City], 
  t2m.Name as MediumCityName, 
  t1.[Big City],
  t2b.Name as BigCityName
From Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2s on t1.[Small City] = t2s.Id
INNER JOIN Table2 t2m on t1.[Med City] = t2m.Id
INNER JOIN Table2 t2b on t1.[Big City] = t2b.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are new to the concept of joins, i think the following way would be best for you to understand what is happening. You will have to execute three joins for that, since you wish to join different columns of table1.

```
select 'Small City', Name from table1 inner join table2 on table1.'Small City' = table2.id

select 'Med City', Name from table1 inner join table2 on table1.'Med City' = table2.id

select 'Big City', Name from table1 inner join table2 on table1.'Big City' = table2.id
```

The solutions which others have suggested are correct, but would be difficult for you to understand since you are entirely new to the concept of joins.